# MVC 3: CustomResult() doesn't find suitable method to override

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-3, overriding

I am creating an imageresult.. but the "public override void ExecuteResult (ControllerContext Context)" says: no suitable method found to overide.

my class looks like this..

```
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext Context)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        string contentType = GetContentTypeFromFile();

        //if there's no context, stop the processing
        if (Context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        //check for file
        if(File.Exists(_path)){
            bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(_path);
        }
        else{
            throw new FileNotFoundException(_path);
        }


        //
        HttpResponseBase response = Context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = contentType;

        MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        while (true)
        {
            int read = imageStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            if (read == 0)
                break;

            response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        response.End();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your class subclass `ActionResult`? Try the following:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class ImageResult : ActionResult 
{
  public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext Context)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: @Freetalk13 override is a feature of .Net, not MVC. It is available in all versions of C#.

Comment: @Freetalk13 Do you have a reference to System.Web.Mvc.dll?

Comment: yes, i had.. after closing, and opening the project, it doesn't show any errors. thanks.
but when I go to 'http://localhost:3761/home/getimage', it displays a server error --> C:\{pathToImage}.jpg  and throw new FileNotFoundException(_path);
how can I pass a path?

Comment: @Freetalk13 I assume `_path` is a field on your ImageResult class, pass it when instantiating your ImageResult (possibly using the HttpServerUtility.MapPath method).